# Can mustache render pice of html multiple times?

Tags: node.js, mustache

I need to make that mustache will render piece of html x times. Is there some specific syntax for it, or do I need to use `{{#list}}` and then use loop inside node.js for placing `{}` inside `{list:[]}` x times?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to provide data in an array and use the `#` template operator such as:

**mustache template**

```
<ul>
{{#items}}
  <li>{{value}}</li>
{{/items}}
</ul>
```

**data**

```
{
  "items": [
    { "value": "hello" },
    { "value": "world" }
  ]
}
```

**rendered html**

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>world</li>
</ul>
```